# How to differentiate the test cases based on its tags?

Tags: rspec, capybara, allure, site-prism

I have one test case which runs for different countries but when I run the entire suite it overrides the test name in allure report. I want to know which test get passed or failed based on its tags. I am using rspec and allure combination.

My Test looks like this:

```
scenario 'Validate order payment flow for credit card', :ae, :bh, :eg, :sa, :db_creation do
    ENV['COUNTRY'] == 'AE' ? @app.order.add_subscription(true) : @app.order.add_product('Featured')
    @app.order.click_on_send_offer_button(true)
    visit(@app.payment.get_payment_page_for_order(@client.get_client_user_id_from_db(@app.users.email_address_data), @client.get_contract_id_from_db(@app.users.email_address_data)))
    @app.payment.payment_form.confirm_order_button.click
    @app.payment.proceed_through_payment_method_screen('credit card', true)
    @app.payment.proceed_through_payment_terms_screen('pay upfront', true)
    @app.payment.proceed_through_payment_schedule_screen('credit card')
    @app.payment.fill_credit_card_payment_details
    @app.payment.check_success_message
  end
```

Just curious if someone tried it anytime. please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You would fix this in your runner.

So in cucumber for instance you would do `cucumber --tags '@abc'`

As you are using allure, look for allure runner docs. That is specifically where it would be altered. SitePrism or RSpec wouldn't handle this for you.